# Javascript - Access The Contents Of A Page That Was Attached With The Embed Tag

Tags: javascript

Using the embed tag, I attached a page (embed.html) to my main page (index.html). How do I access the contents of the embedded page from index.html using Javascript?

The main page (index.html) has the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<!-- Tile outside -->

<h1 id='titleOutsideOfTheEmbedTag'>The Title Outside Of The Embed Tag</h1>

<!-- Embed tag -->

<embed id='embedTag' src='embed.html' width='600' height='400'></embed>

<!-- Buttons -->

<div><button onclick='changeTitleOutsideOfTheEmbedTag()'>Change The Title <strong>Outside</strong> Of The Embed Tag</button></div>
<div><button onclick='changeTitleInsideOfTheEmbedTag()'>Change The Title <strong>Inside</strong> Of The Embed Tag</button></div>

<!-- Functions -->

<script>

// Change the title outside of the embed tag

function changeTitleOutsideOfTheEmbedTag() {

    document.getElementById('titleOutsideOfTheEmbedTag').innerHTML = 'The Title Outside Of The Embed Tag Has Changed';

}

// Change the title inside of the embed tag

function changeTitleInsideOfTheEmbedTag() {

    // I already tried with the following:

    document.getElementById('embedTag').contentWindow.getElementById('titleInsideOfTheEmbedTag').innerHTML = 'The Title Inside Of The Embed Tag Has Changed';

    // document.getElementById('embedTag').contentDocument.getElementById('titleInsideOfTheEmbedTag').innerHTML = 'The Title Inside Of The Embed Tag Has Changed';

}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The embedded page (embed.html) has the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<!-- Set the background color to easily differentiate between the two -->

<style>

body {
    background-color: gray
}

</style>

<!-- Tile inside -->

<h1 id='titleInsideOfTheEmbedTag'>The Title Inside Of The Embed Tag</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

I can change the title of index.html but how do I change the title on the embedded page?

Comment: I would appreciate you reviewing my answer to your question and marking it as accepted, if your question is answered. Thank you

Comment: I clicked on the button to mark it as useful, however, since I don't have enough reputation points, after I click, I get a message saying that my vote will be recorded but won't affect the publicly displayed post score. The solution did help, thank you.

Comment: BTW if I remember correctly, when I signed into stackoverflow.com I read that we should not be adding thank you comments and pretty much unnecessary stuff to make this more readable, informational, and professional hence I never add comments unless I need to further discuss about the question that was asked but I do always avoid small talk in the site.

Comment: Under an answer score you have an acceptance button `v`. It's title is: "Click to accept this answer because it solved your problem or was the most helpful in finding your solution (click again to undo)". You can accept any one of provided answers, and this ability doesn't require any reputation points

Answer (score 0):

Add onload function into `embed.html` and provide a link to the parent html:

```
function init() {
    parent.embedDocument = this.document;
}
```

In the index.html use the following code:

```
function changeTitleInsideOfTheEmbedTag() {
    embedDocument.getElementById('titleInsideOfTheEmbedTag').innerHTML = 'The Title Inside Of The Embed Tag Has Changed';
}
```

Here is both files updated:

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<!-- Tile outside -->

<h1 id='titleOutsideOfTheEmbedTag'>The Title Outside Of The Embed Tag</h1>

<!-- Embed tag -->

<embed id='embedTag' src='embed.html' width='600' height='400'></embed>

<!-- Buttons -->

<div><button onclick='changeTitleOutsideOfTheEmbedTag()'>Change The Title <strong>Outside</strong> Of The Embed Tag</button></div>
<div><button onclick='changeTitleInsideOfTheEmbedTag()'>Change The Title <strong>Inside</strong> Of The Embed Tag</button></div>

<!-- Functions -->

<script>

// Change the title outside of the embed tag

function changeTitleOutsideOfTheEmbedTag() {

    document.getElementById('titleOutsideOfTheEmbedTag').innerHTML = 'The Title Outside Of The Embed Tag Has Changed';

}

// Change the title inside of the embed tag

function changeTitleInsideOfTheEmbedTag() {

    embedDocument.getElementById('titleInsideOfTheEmbedTag').innerHTML = 'The Title Inside Of The Embed Tag Has Changed';

}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

### embed.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="init()">

<!-- Set the background color to easily differentiate between the two -->

<style>

body {
    background-color: gray
}

</style>

<!-- Tile inside -->

<h1 id='titleInsideOfTheEmbedTag'>The Title Inside Of The Embed Tag</h1>

<script>
    function init() {
        parent.embedDocument = this.document;
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

### Important

This solution will work if files are from the same website only!
It won't work if files are loaded in a browser directly from the local drive.

That's a limit of the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)